# Python MySQL SELECT WHERE IN Clause issue

Tags: python, mysql

So I am getting an

> "Unknown Column"

error in this code:

```
SELECT 
 cus_id,
 cus_name, 
 cus_phone 
FROM database.cus_info 
WHERE cus_updated=1 IN ('database.cus_address') # AND cus_id = (database.cus_info.cus_id)
```

basically I need it to look in a different table (`cus_address`) and under column (`cus_updated`) and need it to only grab (`cus_name` and `cus_phone`) if (`cus_updated`) = 1.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Share the structure of these two tables please. And mention how these two tables are related

Comment: I made a couple updates to the above code to get a better idea, the two tables will share the same cus_id. I am not sure what you mean by sharing the structure of the two tables but there are many more columns that what I have listed but are not needed for what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

`INNER JOIN` can help you in this regard.

```
SELECT
 CI.cus_id,
 CI.cus_name,
 CI.cus_phone
FROM database.cus_info CI 
INNER JOIN database.cus_address CA ON CI.cus_id = CA.cus_id 
WHERE CA.cus_updated = 1;
```

I guess `cus_updated` field belongs to `cus_address` table.

---

If you are not familiar with `JOIN` then go through this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join).

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will give this a try tomorrow when I get back to work and will update once I find out how it works out.